# How to render multiple controls one time via icallbackeventhandler method?

Tags: javascript, render, icallbackeventhandler

I am developing one user control which contains 4 dropdwonlists and I may need them select value change bind without post back, now i've met a question which is I can not render multiple controls one time?

Is there any way that we can do this?

Comment: Can you make your question little more descriptive. I simply cannot understand what "select value change bind without post back" means.

Comment: Hi Ankit, i mean when i select one dropdownlist, the second deopdownlist value will bind automaticlly with first dropdownlist selected value.